# Inter-function communication between calling and called functions

Tags: python, function, methods, communication, messaging

I was wondering if there is a clean way to establish some sort of communication between the calling function/method and the called function/method. Say, the caller is part of the main driver program that show the current application status on a UI. It needs to connect to remote network node and for this it calls another method residing in another Python module (in the same thread).

**Main (driver) module:**

```
import ssh_client

node_ip = "10.10.10.10"
node_user = "myuser"
node_pass = "mypass"
conn_result = False

while not conn_result :
    conn_result = ssh_client.connect(node_ip, node_user, node_pass)

    # process custom return codes from connect method here...
```

**ssh_client module:**

```
import paramiko

def connect(node_ip, node_user, node_pass):
    retries_left = 3

    while retries_left > 0:
        try:
            paramiko.SSHClient().connect(node_ip, username=node_user, password=node_pass)
            return True
        except Exception:
            retries_left -= 1

    return False
```

Now, while the network module method attempts to connect, it may run into various issues caused by network latency or other issues and will retry the connection accordingly. At this point, I would like the method to somehow inform my main caller method that the connection has failed and a reconnection is being attempted.

In the above example, I am depending on return codes to get the current connection situation. However, instead of relying on return codes, I want the data *while* the connect method is executing. In other words, when there is an exception, I want the connect method to tell the driver module to tell that there's been an exception and its attempting to reconnect.

While it is possible to achieve this via crude methods like updating the status to a text file and making the caller poll it for status changes, but it doesn't sound like a very convincing solution. Is there anything in Python that can prove handy here, am I missing something obvious? What would be a GOOD way to solve this problem?

Comment: Is making the caller responsible for retrying the connection an option? That seems like the cleaner solution to me. `connect` would then just let the exception bubble up to the caller.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I would like the network module to take care of all re-connections and leave the caller with just the task of calling.

Comment: Unlucky you can no do it like you are planning it, especially not in one thread. What ever kind of infomation is send down the stack it is not processed until the receiver is on top of the stack again. That means the called function has to return (or terminate in any way) first. No two functions on different positions in the stack can run code at the same time.

Comment: If your caller should react to the notifications, you'd have to call `connect` asynchronously in a separate thread or process.

Comment: What on the other is possible is to use a asynchronous franework. There are some, just two names: asyncio and Twisted.

Answer (score 0):

A very naive approach would be something like this:

```
from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue

def connect(queue, *args):
    retries_left = 3

    while retries_left > 0:
        try:
            your_connect_call(*args)
        except Exception:
            queue.put('Error')
            retries_left -= 1

    # Send poison pill to notify the caller that the task is complete
    queue.put(None)
    return False

def caller():
    q = Queue()
    t = Thread(target=connect, args=(q,))
    t.start()
    while True:
        msg = q.get()
        if msg is None:
            break
        print(msg)
    res = t.join()
    return res
```

The caller starts a separate thread and passes a `Queue` to the called method. The called method populates the `Queue` with status notifications, that the caller can react to (here it simply prints these messages). The called method notifies the caller that no more messages are to be expected by sending a `None` signal. The caller waits for that signal and then for the method to return.

Comment: This could definitely work, but I was really looking forward to doing it without getting into threading. Will try this out anyway, thanks.